# MissingOutputException, but indicated files are present

Tags: python, workflow, snakemake

I am running trying to create a pipeline to call germline mutations.
Everything runs fine, until one rule throws a `MissingOutputException`.

The issue is, that the files that are supposedly missing are clearly present, exactly at the paths that are indicated.
If I simply run snakemake again, after the initial run failed (because of the `MissingOutputException`) everything works perfectly fine.

Even more interesting, if I execute the code on my local machine, there is also no error with the initial run. As soon as I run my code on the cluster, the error occures. Increasing `--latency-wait` didnt seem to help.
This is the command that I use:

```sh
snakemake -j 3 --cluster "sbatch --mem={resources.mem_mb} --time {resources.runtime_min} --cpus-per-task {threads} --job-name={rule}.%j --output snakemake_cluster_submit/{rule}.%j.out" -p --latency-wait 200
```

This is how my DAG looks like:

[image]

The error occurs at one of the `MergeHaplotypeCaller` steps.

Any insights why this error might occur is highly appreciated!

Comment: I think it would help to show the rule `MergeHaplotypeCaller`, the output log with error, and the output of `ls` in the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

I simply reran the pipeline again over night and increased the `--latency-wait` even more. Now it works. So it really looks like the filesystem was the problem. Sorry for confusion.